# Variable with same name with a struct type compiling only if it's not a template

Tags: c++, class, templates, language-lawyer, variable-names

Why is it allowed to have a variable with same name with a struct type only if it's not a template?

Why is this considered okay:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    int func(int) const;
};

struct Foo Foo;
```

but not this:

```
template<bool x = true>
struct Foo {
    int func(int) const;
};

struct Foo<> Foo;
```

```
// gcc 11.2

<source>:6:14: error: 'Foo<> Foo' redeclared as different kind of entity
    6 | struct Foo<> Foo;
      |              ^~~
<source>:2:8: note: previous declaration 'template<bool x> struct Foo'
    2 | struct Foo {
      |        ^~~
Compiler returned: 1

// clang 13.0.1

<source>:6:14: error: redefinition of 'Foo' as different kind of symbol
struct Foo<> Foo;
             ^
<source>:2:8: note: previous definition is here
struct Foo {
       ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

https://godbolt.org/z/s94n115fq

Comment: _Why is it allowed to have a variable with same name with a struct type only if it's not a template?_ Because «C compatibility»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (C++ 20, 13 Templates) class template name shall be unique in its declarative region.

> 7 A class template shall not have the same name as any other template,
> class, function, variable, enumeration, enumerator, namespace, or type
> in the same scope (6.4), except as specified in 13.7.6. Except that a
> function template can be overloaded either by non-template functions
> (9.3.4.6) with the same name or by other function templates with the
> same name (13.10.4), a template name declared in namespace scope or in
> class scope shall be unique in that scope.

So for example this declaration in main

```
template<bool x = true>
struct Foo {
    int func(int) const;
};

int main()
{
    struct Foo<> Foo;
}
```

will be correct.

As for these declarations

```
struct Foo {
    int func(int) const;
};

struct Foo Foo;
```

then the declaration of the variable `Foo` hides the name of the declared structure. In C structure tag names and variable names are in different name spaces. So to preserve the compatibility with C such declarations in C++ are allowed.

To refer to the structure type after the variable declaration you need to use the elaborated name of the structure type.